# Fetch specific property in hibernate One-to-many relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two `pojo` classes with `one-to-many relationship` in hibernate

**CustomerAccountEnduserOrderDetails.class**

```
@Entity @Table(name="customer_account_enduser_order_details") 
public class CustomerAccountEnduserOrderDetails  implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CustomerCmsProduct customerCmsProduct;
}
```

Second is **CustomerCmsProduct.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer_cms_product")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomerCmsProduct {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="offer_price")
    private String offerPrice;

    @Column(name="original_price")
    private String originalPrice;

    @Column(name="discount")
    private String discount;
}
```

Here if I fetch the object of `CustomerAccountEnduserOrderDetails` class,then  i will get the `CustomerCmsProduct` class also , my problem is that here **i want the specific column of `CustomerCmsProduct` table** (not all by default i am getting all) like only id and originalPrice.

How i can do like that `projection` here?

Comment: Why do you need to complicate the auto fetch policies of hibernate ? Why cant it be changed to another level where you convert all the Data base objects to a Pojo level in UI ?

Comment: I dint get what you want to say , may you  give an example or tip , how to convert at another level , what i am thinking manually i can set null value for unwanted fields but it is very expensive if i load 100 object at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the service layer or at a webservice layer( if this is a web project) Create two different classes other than `@Entity` as DTO(Data Transfer Objects) which helps is data transfer from one layer to the other.

```
public class CustomerAccountEnduserOrderDetailsPojo {
    private List<CustomerCmsProductPojo> productPojoList = new ArrayList<> ();
    // getter and setter
}

public class CustomerCmsProductPojo {}
```

Follow the below steps

- Retrieve the `@Entity` class data by executing the query from service layer.
- Iterate over all the fields and copy only required fields to pojo layer
- Expose the data to other layers using service method.

This way, we can avoid changing the custom hibernate behavior as it is linked with many parameters like cache, one to many queries that are fired per iteration.

And also, do any customization that you want in this layer. Hope this is multi layered project where you have different layers which servers different purpose.

Comment: ok .. but i want know that is there any annotation where we can specify specific columns that we want to retrieve .. iterating and copying  is very expensive , performance issues will be there .

Comment: AFAIK, we don't have any. You can create a custom annotation based on `AOP` if this is reusable at many places.